# Testing Electron Applications With Robot Framework's Selenium2Library

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, automated-tests, electron, robotframework

I have done everything which is provided in this link - https://spage.fi/electron . Firstly I downloaded the correct version of ***Chromedriver*** for the corresponding ***Electron*** latest stable release and for the ***ubuntu-16.04*** from this link - https://github.com/electron/electron/releases .  And I started the ***chromedriver*** from the terminal

It showed the message like this in ***terminal***

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.30 (7accc8730b0f99b5e7c0702ea89d1fa7c17bfe33) on port 9515
>
> Only local connections are allowed.

Then I created a python file, ***vars.py*** with following content:

```
binary_location = {"chromeOptions": {"binary": "path/to/electron/application"}}
```

And finally created Robot Framework test suite, like this:

```
*** Settings ***

Library      Selenium2Library    run_on_failure=Log Source
Variables    ./vars.py

*** Test Cases ***

Foo
    Create Webdriver    Remote    desired_capabilities=${binary_location}    command_executor=http://localhost:9515
    Sleep    15s
    Click Element    password
    #password is the id of the textfield
    Input Text       password    1234
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

When I run the test in the ***Ride IDE***, The test suite runs and it opens the Electron app and it displays the front page of the app. But after the 15 seconds sleep, the log is showing as

> :  INFO : Clicking element 'password'.

and it continues to run in that state while nothing happens in the electron app

I don't know why its not running the keywords while it runs perfectly in the browser corresponding to the electron app

I changed the ***vars.py*** again as shown below

```
binary_location = {"browserName": "chrome", "chromeOptions": {"binary": "path/to/electron/application"}}
```

I checked this link from the electron docs - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md

Still I'm not getting the reason why it's not working inside the electron app.
Please help me to run the keywords to test the electron app. Is it even possible to test the electron app using Robot Framework??

Comment: It was the problem with the multiple windows. I find out the issue with the help of the keyword `Get Window Handles` or `List Windows`. I selected the window to be tested with the use of the keywords : `Get Window Titles` and `Select Window  ${TITLE_NAME}` . Thanks